# ArgumentCountError in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, findall

I have created 3 course contents. But unfortunately, it only shows 1 course content as what the picture showed below. What I am trying to do is to show ALL the course content that I created earlier. It runs normal when I run with this syntax.

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Coursecontent::findAll()->andFilterWhere(['coursecontent_id' => $id]),
        ]);

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id), 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

[image]

But when I changed my code to this. It shows this error message. What i am trying to do here is to show all the course contents.
**Too few arguments to function yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::findAll(), 0 passed in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\valuefarm\algobox_admin\controllers\CourseController.php on line 57 and exactly 1 expected**

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Coursecontent::findAll()->andFilterWhere(['coursecontent_id' => $id]),
        ]);

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id), 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to fetch the data for `ActiveDataProvider`, it will do it for you.

Just provide the query.

```php
public function actionView($id)
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Coursecontent::find()->andFilterWhere(['coursecontent_id' => $id]),
    ]);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id), 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Your error is `findAll()` expects a condition and will return results, not an `ActiveQuery` instance.

e.g.

```php
Coursecontent::findAll(['coursecontent_id' => $id]);
```

Comment: 'query' => Coursecontent::find()->andFilterWhere(['coursecontent_id' => $id])

Comment: So i should just write like this?

Comment: Yes, `ActiveDataProvider` calls `all()` internally after managing paging etc.

Comment: But still it only shows one "Coursecontent", I have created actually 2 contents

Comment: Im not sure why it keeps showing only one data, its not returning all

Comment: Do those 2 rows in the `Coursecontent` table have the same value in the `coursecontent_id` column?

Comment: Sir you are right, ActiveDataProvider already calls all().

Comment: This is what write later and it doesn't have error.

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Coursecontent::find()->andFilterWhere(['course_id' =>$id,])
        ]);

Comment: Hi Sir could you please help me this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359740/how-to-make-a-yii2-dependent-drop-down-list